# Postgresql , comparar time extraido de um timestamp

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, funções, plpgsql

Necessito extrair as horas e minutos de um timestamp no mysql, eu tentei usar o maketime();

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agendar(dia timestamp) returns bool as 
$$
declare

hora time := extract(hour from dia);
minuto time := extract(minute from dia);

horaminuto := maketime(hora,minuto,0);
```

porém acusa de sintaxe incorreta.
Eu preciso extrair a data e a hora para comparar e ver se o horario do timestamp atingiu ou não um limite de tempo. Por exemplo, um comercio que abre as 9:30 da manhã, preciso verificar se a hora que foi passada no timestamp se passa antes ou depois desse horario

Comment: A assinatura da função make_time é make_time(hour int, min int, sec double precision) e retorna um time. 
A assinatura da função extract é extract(field from timestamp) e retorna um double precision. 
Portanto a declaração das variáveis hora e minuto como time está incorreta, deveriam ser double precision ou mesmo um int.

Comment: Uma dúvida: você está trabalhando com o MySQL (como no texto de sua pergunta) ou com o PostgreSQL (como está na tag)?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem sua função, onde ela retorna o valor, onde declara variável, comparação... Eu estou acostumado com procedimentos ao invés de funções, talvez por isso, mas vamos lá, talvez te ajude um pouco a resolver sem criar uma função.

Você pode extrair as horas através desta função:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetimeVariable, '%H') AS 'hora' FROM tabela
```

Onde o **%H** significa o flag de horas, por exemplo, para extrair minutos seria o flag **%i**:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetimeVariable, '%i') AS 'minuto' FROM tabela
```

Agora se você quer uma maneira mais simples de comparar diretamente, tenta com essa função aqui:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS 'valido' FROM tabelaHorarios
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(primeiroDatetime)) > TIME_TO_SEC('09:30:00') AND
id='1'
```

O que acontece é que, ele vai retornar 0 se o ***primeiroDatetime*** não tiver passado das 9h30, do contrário, um valor maior do que 1, para quantos dados ele encontrar... o id você define qual valor da tabela você quer testar... Por que isso? Provavelmente seu sistema vai comparar 1 mês do comércio, para ver em que dias fechou, certo? Você pode definir um range do mês inteiro e contar quantos dias do mês o comércio abriu após as 9h30...